# Samsung Gear S2 continuous vibrations

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-gear-s2

I am making my watch vibrate on the input from Mobile, it works but when the input is continuous the watch does not keep vibrating continuously, there is always some time interval between,
I am using,

```
function onreceive(channelId, data) {
    //createHTML(data);
    navigator.vibrate(500);
}
```

I understand it has to do with the interval of time which I am giving in the `nevigator.vibrate()` function, but I can not think of any solution. 
Please let me know if there is a way to get continous vibration like we get when for example alarm beeps.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/web/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.web.appprogramming/html/tutorials/w3c_tutorial/device_tutorial/managing_vibration.htm

You can try

navigator.vibrate([300, 0]);

This will cause a pattern based vibration that will trigger and then stop.
That way your latency issue can get a little heartbeat time.